# Usb device wont enumerate after booting kernel on a custom board : usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71

Tags: linux, embedded, usb-device, petalinux

When i plug in my usb device I get the following errors:

```
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci-hcd
usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

NOTE:

But when I fatload image.ub from U-boot command line using the following commands :

```
usb start 
fatload usb 0 0x20000000 image.ub
bootm 0x20000000
```

and don't remove my usb after loading image.ub. It works properly upon boot & i am able to read/write to the device.

But after i disconnect and reconnect the usb device i get the same errors -71 as mentioned above.

From the following behavior, i noticed :

1. That the usb drivers have been loaded, otherwise the fatloading image.ub from u-boot wouldn't have been possible
2. The process of flashing image.ub is an interaction between the board and usb, which might have initialized something before kernel boots up. Hence the usb works after that.

I have configured the system-user.dtsi file with :

```
/include/ "system-conf.dtsi"
/ {
};
&dwc3_0 { 
        dr_mode = "host";
        phy-names = "usb3-phy";
};
```

Also enabled

```
xHCI HCD(3.0)
USB Mass storage support 
Designware USB3 
      DWC mode -> Dual Role mode
```

using petalinux-config -c kernel .

Edit: Since it is a custom board, i can tell u that, we are using Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC.
And I have attached Startup logs and device tree for more information.
[system.dts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HLViKVvllmSXPQGcHk5jDx4wJyo5PmNx/view?usp=sharing) & [startup-logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ihh9cElGgRfYOZgIFIL5hOwN44DhRPd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: the issue could be closely hardware tied; please provide information about that

Comment: @mattia.b89 I have added device tree & startup logs